# Not getting push notification permission alert in android (0.59.8) but it's working in ios

Tags: react-native

I am running sample application.But not getting permission alert in android using react-native-push-notification

I searched in module issues and came across the below link :

https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/1156

### MyCode

> componentWillMount(){
>         PushNotification.configure({
>           // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
>
> ```
>     onRegister(token) {
>       alert(`TOKEN@@@@: ${JSON.stringify(token)}`);
>       deviceType = token.os;
>       deviceToken = token.token;
>     },
>
>     // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
>     onNotification(notification) {
>       console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
>
>       // process the notification
>
>       // required on iOS only (see fetchCompletionHandler docs: 
>    https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html)
>       notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
>     },
>
>     // ANDROID ONLY: GCM or FCM Sender ID (product_number) (optional - not required for 
>     local notifications, but is need to receive remote push notifications)
>     senderID: "301058192164",
>
>     // IOS ONLY (optional): default: all - Permissions to register.
>     permissions: {
>       alert: true,
>       badge: true,
>       sound: true
>     },
>
>     // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
>     // default: true
>     popInitialNotification: true,
>
>     /**
>      * (optional) default: true
>      * - Specified if permissions (ios) and token (android and ios) will requested or not,
>      * - if not, you must call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later
>      */
>     requestPermissions: true
>   });
> }
> ```

expected output:

Need to get permission alert in android using 
 react-native-push-notification

Working environment:
react-native:0.59.8
react-native-push-notification:3.1.9

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native-permissions (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions).

And easily handle your permissions.